# Doxygen project version number in XML

Tags: xml, doxygen

I would like my project version number to appear the the Doxygen XML output so I can programmatically retrieve it. I have set up PROJECT_NUMBER, and the value I used there appears in the HTML output for the same build, but not for the XML output. I grepped the XML output folder for the raw text of the value I put in PROJECT_NUMBER and it appears nowhere. Searching through the Doxygen configuration options I couldn't find anything that would control this besides PROJECT_NUMBER itself, so I don't think it's only a configuration issue.

Is this simply not a feature for Doxygen? If so is there a workaround to get that value in the XML output? The version number is generated during the documentation build process and I would strongly prefer not to store it in any source file directly.

I am using Doxygen 1.8.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No definitive answer, but this is the solution I will be using if nothing else pops up.

Create an alias:

```
ALIASES = "myversion=\anchor version \xmlonly a.b.c \endxmlonly"
```

Where 'a.b.c' is the version number that was also placed in PROJECT_NUMBER.

Then place the `\myversion` tag in a comment block marked as a `\page` or `\mainpage`, since `\anchor` needs to be in one of those ([source](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdanchor)).

It's not ideal, but you can then use the anchor to easily locate the version in the xml. In my case the xml output was:

```
<para><anchor id="index_1version"/> a.b.c </para>
```

within the page's detailed description, so you can just grab the textual contents of the enclosing 'para' tag.

I don't necessarily need the `\xmlonly` tag, but since the PROJECT_NUMBER shows up in the html already, having the version number randomly printed out elsewhere isn't necessary.